# program to check longest palindrome doesnt work

Tags: java

whats wrong with this piece of code.
Doessnt work..returns the entire string reversed...
I am trying to check the longest substring that is a palindrome

i am using the brute force method to check every substring for a palindrome.
Why would this not work

```
public class LongestPalindrome {

    static String s = "yogaranjnarsap";
    static String test = "";
    static String result ="";
    static int resultLen = 0;
    static String temp = "";

    static void checkPalindrome(String str)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

        sb1 = sb.reverse();
        if(sb1.toString().equals(sb.toString()))
        {
            //System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb));

            if(sb.length() > result.length())
            {
                result = sb.toString();
                resultLen = sb.length();
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            temp = "" + s.charAt(i);

            for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
            {
                temp = temp + s.charAt(j);
                checkPalindrome(temp);
                //temp = temp + s.charAt(i);

            }
            temp ="";
        }

        if(result.length() > 1)
        {
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("length" + resultLen);
        }

        else
            System.out.println("no palindrome found");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. Look up how to debug with the IDE you're using and trace out the code line by line. It'll be critical for you to do that rather than have someone dump the answer on you.

Comment: @Kon Thank you boss..i needed that advice !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sb.reverse()` reverses `sb` and returns this object.

Therefore `sb1 = sb.reverse();` will reverse `sb` and assign `sb1` to `sb`.

You want to do:

```
StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder(str);
StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
sb1 = sb.reverse();
```

The `reverse()` method reverses `sb` itself, so `sb` and `sb1` both reference the same `StringBuilder` object, which contains the reverse of `str`. Try this instead of declaring `sb` and `sb1`:

```
String revStr = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

Then simply replace all instances of `sb` and `sb.toString()` with `str` and `sb1.toString()` with `revStr`.